# PyQt6 set position of input field and button

Tags: python, button, pyqtgraph, input-field, pyqt6

I'm trying to create in PyQt6 an input field (location: bottom right of the window) and next to It on the right an "Enter" button (I'm using pg.GraphicView()). I can't use the PySide library because of some interaction problems with the rest of my code. How can I achieve that?

I'm using the following code for generating a button but I can't figure out how to place It at the bottom right of the current window:

```
view = pg.GraphicsView()
l = pg.GraphicsLayout()
view.setCentralItem(l)
view.show()

proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
button = QPushButton("ENTER")
proxy.setWidget(button)

view.addItem(proxy)
```

Regarding the input field I tried to implement different things without using PySide but they didn't worked.

Comment: "I can't use the PySide library because of some interaction problems with the rest of my code." Can you clarify this? And what were your attempts for the line edit? Also, it's unclear if you're referring to PyQt and PySide with sufficient awareness: *both* are python bindings to Qt, they share 99.99% of the language interface (with some slightly differences, mostly due to typing), but they ***cannot*** be used together.

Comment: The interaction problems refers to what you said about PyQt and PySide (since I'm using PyQt I can't use also PySide). Regarding the line_edit attempts I tried this for example:
```
graphic = QGraphicsItem
line = QLineEdit(graphic)

line.move(80, 20)
line.resize(200, 32)
view.addItem(line)```

but It gives the following error: TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QLineEdit(parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt6.sip.wrappertype'
  QLineEdit(str, parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt6.sip.wrappertype'
@musicamante

Comment: Then just use PyQt, not PySide. The functions names are the same (since they come from Qt). QGraphicsItem is an abstract base class, you cannot instantiate it like that, and even then it wouldn't make any sense, since you cannot reparent a widget to a graphics item. Just do the same you did above: create a graphics proxy and add that to the scene.

Comment: ok, and for the position (bottom-right), how can I achieve that? @musicamante

Comment: For this question only, there's no need for this (I'm providing an answer right now), but you can feel free to make a donation by looking at my profile. If you need further help, we'll see :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`pg.GraphicsView` class](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/graphicsview.html) is actually a subclass of [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html), which is a standard QWidget that inherits from QAbstractScrollArea.

This means that we can potentially add any *child* widget to it without interfering with the contents of the scene and also ignoring possible transformations (scaling, rotation, etc.).

The solution, in fact, is quite simple: set the view as parent of the widget (either by using the view as argument in the constructor, or by calling `setParent()`). Then, what's left is to ensure that the widget geometry is always consistent with the view, so we need to wait for resize events and set the new geometry based on the new size. To achieve this, the simplest solution is to create a subclass.

For explanation purposes, I've implemented a system that allows to set widgets for any "corner" of the view, and defaults to the bottom right corner.

Note: since this question could also be valid for Qt5, in the following code I'm using the "old" enum style (`Qt.Align...`), for newer versions of Qt (and mandatory for PyQt6), you need to change to `Qt.Alignment.Align...`.

```py
class CustomGraphicsView(pg.GraphicsView):
    toolWidgets = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.toolWidgets = {}

    def setToolWidget(self, widget, position=Qt.AlignBottom|Qt.AlignRight):
        position = Qt.AlignmentFlag(position)
        current = self.toolWidgets.get(position)
        if current:
            current.deleteLater()
        self.toolWidgets[position] = widget

        widget.resize(widget.sizeHint())

        # ensure that the widget is reparented
        widget.setParent(self)

        # setParent() automatically hides widgets, we need to
        # explicitly call show()
        widget.show()

        self._updateToolWidgets()

    def _updateToolWidgets(self):
        if not self.toolWidgets:
            return
        viewGeo = self.rect()
        for pos, widget in self.toolWidgets.items():
            rect = widget.rect()
            if pos & Qt.AlignLeft:
                rect.moveLeft(0)
            elif pos & Qt.AlignRight:
                rect.moveRight(viewGeo.right())
            elif pos & Qt.AlignHCenter:
                rect.moveLeft(viewGeo.center().x() - rect.width() / 2)
            if pos & Qt.AlignTop:
                rect.moveTop(0)
            elif pos & Qt.AlignBottom:
                rect.moveBottom(viewGeo.bottom())
            elif pos & Qt.AlignVCenter:
                rect.moveTop(viewGeo.center().y() - rect.height() / 2)
            widget.setGeometry(rect)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self._updateToolWidgets()


# ...

view = CustomGraphicsView()
l = pg.GraphicsLayout()
view.setCentralItem(l)
view.show()

container = QFrame(autoFillBackground=True, objectName='container')
container.setStyleSheet('''
    QFrame#container {
        background: palette(window);
        border: 1px outset palette(mid); 
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
''')
lineEdit = QLineEdit()
button = QPushButton("ENTER")
frameLayout = QHBoxLayout(container)
frameLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
frameLayout.addWidget(lineEdit)
frameLayout.addWidget(button)
view.setToolWidget(container)

bottomLeftButton = QPushButton('Something')
view.setToolWidget(bottomLeftButton, Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignBottom)
```

Comment: "Qt.AlignRight" would become "Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight" correct? Because It says there isn't a method "Alignment" in Qt so If I do "Qt.Alignment.AlignRight" It gives an error. Furthermore, in "QFrame(autoFillBackground=True, objectName='container')" It says that there are two unexpected arg. @musicamante

Comment: The scaling of the button Is not necessary (I've found a work around for that), I just need the buttons to be shown in the bottom-right corner, how can I do that? @musicamante

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot about the name change for `AlignmentFlag`. QFrame instead should actually take those arguments, as they are properties. Is that a warning from the IDE? If that's the case, you can ignore it. Note that, as per your tag, this is for PyQt6, I don't remember if PySide is able to get the properties from keyword arguments, but since you are not using PySide, that's not an issue. Besides, the code above does exactly what you asked, and has absolutely no relation with scaling: as I explained, the widgets are *not* added to the scene, but to the view.